How do I configure two security filter chains so that if unauthorised, only one redirects with the oath2Login, and the other returns 403
I have a spring cloud gateway (gateway-mvc 4.5) and I am hoping to redirect any /ui access to oath2 login authentication server and any api calls to fail if there is no valid authentication in the session. /ui works, but /api always fail with 403.
My config is...
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain_UI(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                           final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) throws Exception {

    // This security filter chain if for the UI which will redirect to the oath2 login if not authorised.
    var ret = httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .requestMatchers("/ui/**").authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oAuth2LoginSpec -> oAuth2LoginSpec
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler()))
            .logout(logoutSpec -> logoutSpec
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGOUT_URL, "GET"))
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)))
            .cors(cors -> cors
                    .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .build();
    return ret;
}

And
@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain_API(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                        final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) throws Exception {

    // This security filter chain if for the APIs which will fail if not authorised.
    return httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges -> exchanges
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // Don't authenticate the actuator
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated())
        .build();
}

Is this the right way top go about this?
When i debug, i see that only the /ui filter chain is being called for /api (looking at the mappings in RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager) Which suggests that securityFilterChain_API just hasn't worked.
If I were to do this with one security filter chain, i would have to override the OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter to not redirect on /api, which is extremely difficult without copying a lot of final classes and modifying them.

So I found out what i needed to do to configure two security chains one UI chain to redirect to oath2 login when required and another REST api chain to just fail when authentication has expired.
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain_UI(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                           final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) throws Exception {
    // This security filter chain is for the UI which will redirect to the oath2 login if not authenticated.
    return httpSecurity
            .securityMatcher("/ui/**", "/oauth2/**", "/login/**", "/logout/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .requestMatchers("/ui/**").authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults()) // Redirect to the oath2 login if not authorised.
            .cors(withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain_API(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // This security filter chain is for the APIs which will fail if not authorised and actuator which is not
    return httpSecurity
            .securityMatcher("/api/**", "/actuator/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()) // Don't authenticate the actuator.
            .oauth2Client(withDefaults()) // Ensure authenticated with token.
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .build();
}

The key was to use the securityMatcher to restrict the security filter chains to the paths for oath2Login, for UI paths, and oath2Client for REST apis.
And also to allow the oath2, login and logout paths abck onto the UI security filter chain.
With TRACE logging on you can see the UI chain has the following filters enabled...
Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain 
[RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/ui/**'], Mvc [pattern='/oauth/**'], Mvc [pattern='/oauth2/**'], Mvc [pattern='/logout/**'], Mvc [pattern='/login/**']], Filters=[
org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@748101e8, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3cf3da1a, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3e285e0c, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7a410a0d, 
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@fe88dcc, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2ce526ae, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@628d6d8f, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@c44a64e, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6202b9a7, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@276c6e69, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6a040463, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5b25f8b2, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5b1eb52d, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5d4f0c7d, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4a4a669d]] (1/2)

And the API chain...
Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain 
[RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/api/**'], Mvc [pattern='/actuator/**']], Filters=[
org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4f5ccf1c, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@49802c40, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4d085b84, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4584b0d4, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@12fcbb79, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@51e2481d, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@25e7d7e9, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5dcca676, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter@453ba9ce, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7050842c, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4a5e76ce]
] (2/2)

